# AngularJS - How to watch model that is used in two controllers without using $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, view, angularjs-scope, uislider, watch

I have two different views that has volume sliders.
I have $watch for each volume slider model and when it is changed I call the setVolume method.

```
$scope.$watch("speakerVolume", function () {
   voipService.SpeakerVolumeChange($scope.speakerVolume * 655);  
});
```

I want to watch the changed volume in a way that whenever I change the volume in one slider it will be changed also in the second one.
I have heard that i can put the model in $rootScope and then watch on it.
Is there another solution for that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the first parameter watchExpression with a function like :

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, voipService) {
  $scope.speakerVolume = voipService.speakerVolume;
  $scope.$watch("speakerVolume", function (newValue) {
    voipService.speakerVolume = newValue;
  });
});

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function($scope, voipService) {
  $scope.$watch(function () { return voipService.speakerVolume }, function (newValue) {
    $scope.speakerVolume = newValue;
  });
});

app.service('voipService', function() {
  this.speakerVolume = 2;
});
```

With two data-binding :

```
<p ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="speakerVolume" />
  {{speakerVolume}}
</p>
<p ng-controller="SecondCtrl">{{speakerVolume}}</p>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mjjjKdD2mfLDXnGwIwFX)

Comment: Thanks. It's a nice solution however it does not fit to my problem since i need it two way binding and here it is one way. and if i do two watches i will end up with loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using watchers is always kind of ugly.

Maybe this https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers will help you.

Services are singletons and there is only 1 instance in angular. 
If you set attributes on the service, pass the service to controllers and bind this attribute to the scope, it wont loose the 2-way binding.

I'd recommend you to use the watcher in the service and have 2 variables: 1 the watcher is watching and 1 that actually carries the value.